# Custom Expcetion not throwing

Tags: java

The exception is never shown .
extended `Exception` class and override the method `toString`.and then called it.according to the condition it should display hahah , but it doesn't show anything..no errors either.

```
class Excp extends Exception {

        public String toString() {
            return "hahah";

        }
    }

    public class exc {

        boolean a = false;

        void hey() throws Excp {

            if (a)
                throw new Excp();

        }

        public static void main(String... s) {

            try {
                new exc().hey();
            } catch (Excp e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition

```
if(a)
```

will return false as you have intiialized `a=false`. Hence the `if` block will not execute the statement

```
throw new Excp();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
{
    if(a)
    throw new Excp();
}
```

A is `false`. Never goes in side the condition, because you haven't making true while initializing the object.

Try

```
try
    {   
        Excp exc = new Excp();
        exc.a= true;
        exc.hey();
    }
```

**Side notes:**

1)Please follow naming conventions.

2)Provide encapsulation.

3)Format your code always.

Comment: and i feel extremely dumb now :( .what a lousy mistake

Comment: @user2837260  No issues. Happens to every programmer someday.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to have a custom exception with your own error message, If so you can do like this

```
class MyException extends Exception{
    MyException(String errorMsg){
         super(errorMsg);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
          if(someCondition)
               throw new MyException("My error message");
    }
}
```